# Can I disable val_loss caculation in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, loss

Actually I want to use different loss functions in training and validation phase. I tried in_tarin_phase but it doesn't work.

So I just wonder can I disable the val_loss calculation?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you not just create your own custom metric that keras will evaluate in addition to regular loss?

Answer (score 0):

Below has a custom loss function:

```
# Build a model
inputs = Input(shape=(128,))
layer1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
layer2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(layer1)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(layer2)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

# Define custom loss
def custom_loss(layer):

    # Create a loss function that adds the MSE loss to the mean of all squared activations of a specific layer
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true) + K.square(layer), axis=-1)

    # Return a function
    return loss

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss(layer), # Call the loss function with the selected layer
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train
model.fit(data, labels)
```